# Как можно динамически обновить iframe без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, iframe

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqiaZ.png это скрин кода

есть вот такой код мне нужно что бы iframe динамически обновлялся но этого не выходит помогите пожалуйста

Comment: по таймеру или после какого то действия?

Comment: а допустим по требованию? например кнопкой и после нажатия обновляетcя iframe как реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Обновить фрейм можно вот так:

`document.getElementById('iframe').src = document.getElementById('iframe').src;`